# Does a basement bathroom exhaust fan duct need to be insulated?

Tags: bathroom, insulation, ducts, fans, moisture

[image]

We have a bathroom in a finished basement.
While removing the old bathroom fan I discovered that the duct pipe leading outside is not insulated.

**Should the bathroom fan duct be insulated traveling inside the joist space? What are the risks if it is not?**

From what I have researched, bathroom fan ducts should be insulated when "traveling through an un-conditioned space", like an attic.
Does the space between the joists in the basement count as un-conditioned?

- The duct runs about 20 feet to the side of the house
- There is a strange vertical "S"-shaped bend in the middle.
- The run appears to be roughly 10 feet on each side, with the S in the middle.

The duct also sits right next to a hot air vent. Is this all the more reason to insulate it? Is there a risk that the hot air duct gets hot enough to melt e.g. a vinyl wrapping around the insulation sleeve?

If I insulate both ends, am I just creating more problems for myself by making the condensation form in the middle of the "S", where I can't reach it?
Would it be better to leave the entire thing, and have the condensation happening at the fan?

Comment: Somewhat off-topic: When the fan is running can you actually feel air blowing at the outside vent? 20 feet is a long way to go and that S-bend in the middle only adds resistance. You might need a higher power fan to get enough airflow to be truly effective. To the point of your question, since there's a bathroom in the basement, it's likely that the basement is _inside_ the HVAC envelope, therefore it's running in conditioned space and your researched caution isn't of concern to you.

Comment: Actually, the hot air duct next to the bathroom vent duct will help _prevent_ condensation, at least along that stretch - it will keep the duct from getting cold enough (when the heat is blowing) for condensation to form there.

Comment: `the basement is inside the HVAC envelope` - Hello, thank you. Yes, the basement is finished and (hopefully!) inside the HVAC envelope. I have edited the question to clarify that the basement is a finished space.

Comment: `the hot air duct next to the bathroom vent duct will help` - As I see the joist space should be considered a conditioned space, yes this makes sense.

Comment: `When the fan is running can you actually feel air blowing at the outside vent?` - This is indeed exactly the question I want to answer. Once I get the new fan installed that will be the test - to see if air actually makes it outside. I am definitely open to increasing the CFM if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the basement is conditioned and the floor above is conditioned, the joist space is conditioned.

Having a basement bathroom implies that the basement is conditioned.

Comment: Hello, thank you. Yes - the basement is indeed finished and conditioned. I will also edit this into my question.

Comment: I suppose now I have the inverse question - if I discover an insulated duct line in a conditioned space, should I _remove_ the insulation?
i.e. if I discovered this same bathroom duct was wrapped in insulation, would it have been better to remove it?

Comment: @culix then post that as a new question.

Comment: Ergo, you do not need insulation because the moist air, traveling through the duct, will not hit any cold metal it could condense on.